# Discontinuous $ f : \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$ with unusual topology on $ \mathbb R$

Tags: general-topology, group-theory

With the usual topology on the reals  $\mathbb R$ , let $D$ be the family of dense open sets and let $T=D \cup \{ \phi \}$.  Let $S$ be the set $R$ with the topology $T$ on it.  Show that the function $f(x,y)=x+y$ from $S^2$ to $S$ is not continuous.  (I was considering the definition of a topological group $G$, where $g(a,b)=ab$ is continuous from $G^2$ to $G$, and I wanted an example where it is insufficient for $g$ to be continuous in each variable separately.)

Comment: If $U$ is a dense open subset of $\mathbb{R}$ (in the standard topology), and $V$ is any nonempty open subset of $\mathbb{R}$ (again in the standard topology), then $U + V = f(U\times V) = \mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: Let $A=\{\langle x,y\rangle\in S^2:x+y\in S\setminus\Bbb Z\}$; $S\setminus\Bbb Z$ is open in $S$, so it suffices to show that $A$ is not open in $S^2$. Suppose that $U$ and $V$ are non-empty open sets in $S$. To show that $A$ is not open in $S^2$ it suffices to show that $U\times V$ meets the line $x+y=0$, i.e., that there is an $x\in U$ such that $-x\in V$. In other words, it suffices to show that if $U$ is a dense open set in $\Bbb R$, then $U\cap(-U)\ne\varnothing$.

Comment: ...and  $ U \cap (-U0 \ne \phi $ because they're both dense open in the reals

Comment: @user254665: Yep; you’ve got it.